# ¿Porque articulos.producto es nulo?

Tags: reactjs, api, rest, null

Cordial Saludo.
Me encuentro aprendiendo React, y al realizar un console.log(articulos) en DetallesPedido.js:

```
<ul>
{pedido.pedido.map(articulos => (console.log(articulos)))}
</ul>
```

En la consola me imprime Object { producto: null, cantidad: 1, _id: "63ee9a44a168c91d7019bb88" }

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
El cual al ingresar el siguiente código en el archivo mencionado

```
<ul>
{pedido.pedido.map(articulos => (
<li key={pedido._id+articulos.producto._id}>
<p>{articulos.producto.nombre} </p>
<p>Precio: ${articulos.producto.precio} </p>
<p>Cantidad: {articulos.cantidad}</p>
</li>
))}
</ul>
```

me dice que es nulo (TypeError: articulos.producto is null).
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He buscado el error en la API-REST y no lo encuentro, al igual que en el front.
Agradezco de antemano a la persona que me colabore y me de una explicación de como solucionarlo.
Adjunto Print

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quedo atento a cualquier pregunta acerca del proyecto de prueba en el que estoy aprendiendo.

Comment: Hola Brayam martinez perdomo, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, elimines las imágenes, y adjuntes tu código y los mensajes de error como texto, así evitarás recibir votos negativos. Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta,

Comment: Pero si en los datos hay un `producto=null`... que esperas que suceda? tienes un producto = null... debes es arreglar los datos, no la lógica... o si tener producto = null es valido, entonces debes ajustar tu logica para cuando es null y para cuando no lo es